# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Enterprise_Rma_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Renderer' not found in \lib\Varien\Data\Form\Abstract.php on line 146

Tags: magento

Im migrating magento Enterprise edition to community edition. Im almost done. But having only one problem in backend.If I go to Manage Products and click on any products im getting this error.

**Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Enterprise_Rma_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Renderer' not found in magento\lib\Varien\Data\Form\Abstract.php on line 146**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your database locate the 'eav_attribute' table and delete the line with the attribute_code 'is_returnable'

Comment: I did that but now im getting  Fatal error:Class 'Mage_Enterprise_Giftwrapping_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Helper_Form_Config' not found in magento\lib\Varien\Data\Form\Abstract.php on line 146

Comment: I found solution for this problem. solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467612/fatal-error-class-mage-enterprise-giftwrapping-block-adminhtml-product-helper/13467866#13467866

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Use this for downgrading, then everything will be fine:

```
    DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE `attribute_code` = 'giftcard_amounts';
    DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE `attribute_code` = 'related_tgtr_position_limit';
    DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE `attribute_code` = 'related_tgtr_position_behavior';
    DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE `attribute_code` = 'upsell_tgtr_position_limit';
    DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE `attribute_code` = 'upsell_tgtr_position_behavior';
    DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE source_model LIKE 'enterprise_%';
    DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE backend_model LIKE 'enterprise_%';
    DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code IN ('gift_wrapping_available', 'gift_wrapping_price');
```