# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Enterprise_Giftwrapping_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Helper_Form_Config' not found in ...\..\Abstract.php on line 146

Tags: magento

Im migrating magento Enterprise edition to community edition. Im almost done. But having few problem in backend.If I go to Manage Products and click on any products im getting this error.

**Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Enterprise_Giftwrapping_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Helper_Form_Config' not found in ...\lib\Varien\Data\Form\Abstract.php on line 146**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution for this problem. Search for this keyword in your **catalog_eav_attribute** table **"enterprise_giftwrapping/adminhtml_product_helper_form_config"** and change the field **`is_visible` = '0'**.

This solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks, the query for this is `UPDATE catalog_eav_attribute SET is_visible = 0 WHERE frontend_input_renderer = 'enterprise_giftwrapping/adminhtml_product_helper_form_config';`